# External css linked correctly, but only inline style works

Tags: css, inline-styles

I have got a working css linked to an html. I tried adding style for a link in the external css file but that didn't work:

```
.list-container li a, .list-container li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
```

The html:

```
<ul class="list-container">
     {% for skill in skills %}
            <li style="--color: {{skill.color}};">
                <a href="random.html">
                <div class="card-content">
                    <h2>{{skill.name}}</h2>
                    <span>Master</span>
                </div>
                </a>
            </li>
      {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I tried different variants but this does not work. However inline style does work:

```
<a style="text-decoration: none; color: white;" href="random.html">
```

But I would like it better in the external file. How would I do that?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: @Hummingbird unfortunately your comment did not help me that much. The external css is set up correctly since it works for other attributes, but somehow for this external statement it only shows the default.

Answer (score 0):

I found Out why It was not working. My browser had saved the external css file in a cache and therefore changes were not comming through. So  I emptied the cache and now everything works fine.